# How to save static page attributes in User model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

**Requirement:** I need to create a single page application in ROR where user can change the background color of page, font and that change should persist with user sessions.

**What I am doing is:** I have created a controller static_pages with home as index and created a form under its view that named as home.html.erb.

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => url_for(:controller => 'static_pages', :action => 'home') do |u| %>

 <br > 
 <p>
    <%= u.label :title %><br>
    <%= u.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= u.label :description %><br>
    <%= u.text_field :description %>
  </p>

  <p> <%= u.label :back_ground_color %><br>
    <select name="bgcolor" id="bgcolor">
        <option value="#FF3300">Orange</option>
        <option value="#00FF00">Green</option>
        <option value="#0000FF">Blue</option>
        <option value="#FF0066">Pink</option>
        <option value="#FFFF00">Yellow</option>
        <option value="#FFFFFF">White</option>
    </select>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= u.label :font %><br>
    <select name="font" id="font">
        <option value="Times New Roman">Times new Roman</option>
        <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
        <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
        <option value="sans-serif">serif</option>
    </select>
  </p>

 <br >
  <p>
    <%= u.submit %>
  </p>
  <hr >
  <div style="background-color:#{current_user.font.nil? ? '#FFFFFF' : current_user.font}">
    This is the changes made in background
  </div>

  <div style="background-color:#{current_user.bgcolor.nil? ? '#FFFFFF' : current_user.bgcolor}">

  </div>

<% end %>
```

I have created this form for user who currently logged in the application and I have used devise gem for this.Now if user fill this form and submit it has to change the background color of page and I am trying to save this in user database. The schema for User is as:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.text     "title"
    t.string   "bgcolor"
    t.text     "description"
    t.text     "font"
  end
```

and I am handling this data in controller as static_pages_controller.rb

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @user = User.new(params.require(:user).permit(:title, :description, :font, :bgcolor))
    if @user.save
      redirect_to '/static_pages/home'
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Developers to be blamed !!"
    end 
  end
end
```

When I am submitting this form I am getting the error as below:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: user
```

Notes: routes.rb looks like this

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations" }
  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do
      root :to => 'static_pages#home', as: :authenticated_root
    end
    unauthenticated :user do
      root :to => 'devise/registrations#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end
  end
```

Please guide where I am doing mistake !!! and thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure there are no `do |u|` at the end of the first line of your view? If so, where does the `u` variable come from?

Comment: Sorry , i edited again, there is do

Comment: There should be a list of parameters on the error page, could you paste it?

Comment: parameter is none, and the error is as { ActionController::ParameterMissing in StaticPagesController#home,  param is missing or the value is empty: user}

Answer (score -1):

Try redirecting to `root_path` instead of `'/static_pages/home'`

You'll probably have a different problem though: `@user.save` will try to save a new user instead of updating the existing one.

Also consider implicitly rendering the view instead of explicitly redirecting back to the same path. That way, the entire if/else block can be reduced to: `flash[:notice] = "Developers to be blamed !!" unless @user.save`

Further note: Single page applications are mostly rendered on the client. The controllers should still be designed according to REST principles.

Comment: It will really help if u suggest how the design should be

Comment: That's quite a large chunk to describe. 
http://www.theodinproject.com/ruby-on-rails/routing should give you a decent overview on what RESTful routes are. In this context, you'd POST to a `UsersController` with an update action. 
The client would update itself with an AJAX / websockets call instead of being rendered from the server.

Comment: let me create the user controller and do in that way then